# Im trying to create an Angular app from tutorial on youtube, Im using Bootstrap modal. The Add department button is not working after clicking on that

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, webapi

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  float-right  m-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#exampleModal" (click)= "addClick()" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Add Department
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> {{ModalTitle}} </h5>
            <button type="button" class="close"
           data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
           (click)=  "closeClick()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <app-add-edit-dep   [dep]= "dep"   *ngIf= "ActivateAddEditDepComp"></app-add-edit-dep>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>DepartmentId</th>
        <th>Department Name</th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let dataItem of DepartmentList">
        <td>{{dataItem.DepartmentId}}</td>
        <td>{{dataItem.DepartmentName}}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1">
                    Edit
                </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1">
                    Delete
                </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you please share the correct code of your button and the modal popup?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define your modal. You can add it in your html as if it were a component or you can activate it in your name.component.ts.

First Example (Never Used)

```
<modal-component #example-modal></modal-component>
```

Second Example (I've always used this)

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="your class" (click)="this.openModal($event)"></button>
```

TS

```
openModal($event) {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent, {
  scrollable: false,
  size: 'lg', 
  windowClass: 'your-custom-class',
  centered: false,
  backdrop: 'static',
});
```

docs --> https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: you can find docs [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)